# Can You Make Vim Move to Next Line When Moving Cursor

Tags: text, vim, ide

If my cursor is at the end of the line and I press right again it will move to the next line like a normal text editor. Is this possible to do?

Comment: A side note: trying to make Vim behave "like a normal text editor" (whatever that may be) is the path to unhappiness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:help 'whichwrap'` is the option you are looking for.

I'm not sure at which stage of your Vim journey you are, but it feels very weird after years of experience with the default behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I put "set ww=[,]" in ~/.vimrc

Comment: If the left-right arrow keys did that, but not `h` and `l`, that might be a reasonable compromise. :)